# How do I write to use Dictionary<T,U>.Enumerator with @:native extern

Tags: haxe

It seems

```
@:native('System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary')
extern class Dictionary<T, U>
```

is valid, but it does not seems to apply to nested class of generic class.

I want to write in Haxe, with my own 'extern class' bridge, something like:

```
struct K {
   string x;
}

struct V {
   string y;
}

class Foo {
   public void foo(Dictionary<K, V> d) {
       Dictionary<K,V>.Enumerator e = d.GetEnumerator();
       while (e.MoveNext()) {
          Debug.Log(e.Current.Key.x);
          Debug.Log(e.Current.Value.y);
       }   
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more context? Which target are you writing for? What error message are you encountering?  Do you have a complete and compile-able code sample you can share?

Comment: The target is C#.  I want to access System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<T,U>.Enumerator with "@:native extern".  But I can not quite imagine the syntax, so that there is no compilation error yet.

Comment: You should post some working C# code, so we can try to help you convert that into Haxe.